# Installing Gemalto Developer Suite on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7-x64

How can I install Gemalto Developer Suite on Windows 7?

I've tried all the compability options, and even extracting the setup files and running those with Windows XP compability turned on, but I always get "The operating system is not adequate for running Developer Suite".

I'm using Developer Suite 3.4.2 on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

---

There is an option for "Show the Windows Installer log" when the the install has failed, but this just shows a dialog box with the message "Error 2732.Directory Manager not initialized".

I'm also running the installer as Administrator

The developer suite installs fine in Windows XP Mode, but it's really slow to use this way unfortunately (even with 4G ram and SSD), and tends to crash a lot.

---

If you try and install it without the updater, it does semi-work - you get what appears to be a functional eclipse install, but without any of the Gemalto tools or the Java Card SDK.

Comment: I know it's been a year - but I hope you'll see this: http://developer.gemalto.com/home.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this can't be done in a meaningful way, or the product is obscure enough that this will not get answered.

Answer (score 0):

install a a virtual machine.....that is running windows xp....then install the software in the virtual machine